# Python 3 Graphics Programming: how can I get a mouse click within a polygon shape?

Tags: list, python-3.x, graphics, 2d, mouseclick-event

So I'm working on a project for a class and I'm still trying to figure out how to go about doing something.

I am making a game where there is a board of squares or hexagons, they are either black or white, each being a state of being "Flipped", and when you click one square/hexagon, it flips all the adjacent shapes too.

Here is an image of what I am aiming to create.
[Assignment images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9LnA.png)

I have gotten it running with squares, but now I need to do it with Hexagons. With the squares I registered a mouseclick as being within a square parameters of the x and y location of the click, and the state changes are assigned to a list of values assigned similarly to how the shapes were assigned within a list.

I will include a quick recording of the square program running in a folder I'm going to link.

Now, I believe I can't apply this kind of system to hexagons since they don't really line up like the squares did.

So how would I go about making a click register within a single hexagon on a grid?  I have already drawn out the grid, but I am stuck on what to do to register a click to allow a hexagon to change it's state from un-flipped to flipped.  I'm pretty sure I know what to do for the state change itself, but I don't know how to go about this, would it involve something with making a separate Class or something?  I would appreciate any help with this.

I'll put a dropbox link here for the progress I made so far, and a pdf manual for graphics.py.

[Dropbox: Python files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2tdsllelsrkrbcq/AAAccE2l0L-nBjrty0z8wVB6a?dl=0)

You can view the python code in your web-browser with dropbox too, I don't really want to fill this page pull of an entire thing of code..

Any help and feedback would be wonderful, thank you c:

so, TL;DR:  How do you register a click within a polygon shape in python that allows it to change a value (within a list?) and change its visual appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the general side of your question, you can use a test to check if a point (x, y) is inside a polygon (formed by a list of x, y pairs).

Here's one such solution: http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html

```
# determine if a point is inside a given polygon or not
# Polygon is a list of (x,y) pairs.
def point_inside_polygon(x,y,poly):
    n = len(poly)
    inside =False

    p1x,p1y = poly[0]
    for i in range(n+1):
        p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y,p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xinters = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y
    return inside
```

This can be used in a way that is quite symmetrical to your drawing code, as you also form polygons in the same way for drawing as you would to test to see if the cursor is inside a hex.

You can modify the above implementation also to work with this `Point` type you are using to draw the polygons.

The rest you should be able to figure out, especially considering that you managed the input handling and drawing for the square grid.